# real function derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be a real function not identically zero in $Z$, such that $\forall x,y \in \Bbb R$.
$$f(x+y^{2n+1})= f(x) + (f(y))^{2n+1} ; n\in\Bbb N $$
If $f'(0)\ge0$ then $f'(6)=?$

Given Answer is 1. How so ?

Comment: Write down the difference quotient at $x = 6$, and see if you can simplify it using the above relation, so that it's limit is evaluable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the difference quotient at $6$ gives $\frac{f(6 + h^{2n+1}) - f(6)}{h^{2n+1}}$. Using the relation given to us, we note that this is equal to $\frac{f(h)^{2n+1}}{h^{2n+1}}$.

Note that the difference quotient is independent of which point we choose it at: this means that $f'(6) =  f'(0)$ (that is, the derivative at $6$ exists and equals the derivative at $0$).

Furthermore, note that $f(0) = 0$, so that $f'(0)  = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}$. However, from the above, it is also equal to $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)^{2n+1}}{h^{2n+1}}$. If we write $f'(0) = L$, this gives $L^{2n+1} = L$, which on solving for non-negative $L$ gives $L = 1$. Hence, $f'(6) = f'(0) = 1$.

NOTE : Since the derivative is equal everywhere, we conclude that $f$ is actually a linear function i.e. $f(x)= Ax + B$ for all $x,y$. In fact, since we know the derivative, we conclude that $A = 1$ and substituting $x = 0$ gives $B = 0$. Therefore, $f(x) = x$ for all $x$, *if $f$ is differentiable* and satisfies the above condition.

Comment: Interesting question : If I don't allow $f$ to be differentiable, is it still true that $f(x) = x$ for all $x$?